# Node JS conditional Zlib Transform stream

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I'm newby in streams. I need create a conditional Zlib Transform stream. It's not working, no errors appears

```
import stream from 'stream';
import zlib from 'zlib';


export class GunzipConditionalFilter extends stream.Transform {

  public Filter: stream.Transform;

  constructor() {
    super();
    if (condition === true) {
      this.Filter = zlib.createGunzip();
    }
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    if (this.Filter !== undefined) {
      this.Filter._transform(chunk, encoding, callback);
      // this.Filter.write(chunk); // Not working either
    } else {
      this.push(chunk);
      callback();
    }
  }

}
```